# Should we burninate the [pyth] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

The [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag contains 1 question only, so should we remove it from the site?

It contains a tag wiki excerpt:

> Pyth is a esoteric procedural programming language which is designed to be compiled into Python. Its primary purpose is conciseness, without sacrificing clarity. It is primarily used for code-golfing.

But it's really looking UN-useful on stack-overflow.

Should we Burninate?

Comment: [See here for info on when and how to burninate a tag.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it doesn't meet any of the burnination criteria. Even if there's only one question with this tag now, the tag actually applies to the question. It also unambiguously identifies an actual topic, and the topic it identifies is clearly on-topic here.

Comment: Oh that's true, i think i wanna delete my question.

Comment: @U9-Forward I don't see why you would delete question - it is well on-topic (value of a tag on SO), good quality and has an answer. Removal will potentially lead to someone else asking the same question...

Comment: @U9-Forward Please do not retag the single question for this tag, since it is valid - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670636/i-dont-understand-the-error-traceback-gives-me. I've rolled back your edits.

Comment: Btw, there were multiple cases of removing this tag - by mistake or intentionally, I don't know. I've rolled back these edits 3 times.

Comment: The problem is: this tag is frequently popping up if you start to type "python" in tag section. I think this is a reason people trying to get rid of it..