# Should there be a procedure to create the new tag that involves the community and experts?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system, tag-creation-process

In current implementation, tag creation is simple. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/5779732), any user with more than 1500 reputation can just type any string in the Tags box while asking/editing the question and that's it.

> To create a tag, one must apply it to a question. Any user with at least 1500 reputation may add new tags to any question by typing the new tag into the question tags field, and submitting1.
>   A tag can be created by adding it to a new question, or by editing it into an existing question. The person who adds the new tag is the creator of the tag.

So, tag creation is simple. If we look at the "Total Reputation" section in [Stack Overflow League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) page, too many user qualify criteria of 1500+ reputation.

This causes creating many bad tags. Fortunately, if tag is not associated to any question, it gets deleted automatically through script. But still, many bad tags stay and other user use it.

Community have to [put](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386588/5779732) up [huge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385502/typo-in-salary-calculator-slack-preview#comment700395_385502) efforts to handle (burnation, rename, merge, synonym etc.) these bad tags survived. Many such requests are pending. [Apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386489/we-dont-need-this-in-our-tag-inventory#comment706446_386489), no enough members are participating in the process. Moderators are limited and thus their time; they also have to look at priorities.

We already have procedure to alter (rename, merge, synonym etc.) existing tag, which needs involvement of community and approval from experts from domain. Similarly, there should be procedure to create the tag. I hope this will considerably bring down the load of managing the tags.

Let us not make too much changes. Let the creation stay the same. Just add some procedure after that. For example:

- User creates the tag the way they are doing now.
- This tag should be added in some queue or similar. While in queue, do not allow to add this tag to any other question. This way, we are controlling the spread of virus.
- Community (hopefully) will review the tag. Allow access of this feature for users based on reputation (lets say 5000+).
- If not on-topic, they will vote to delete the tag. After reaching certain vote count, tag will be deleted. I am not going into details like what if only one tag was added to the questions. This is just a sample of proposal and open for discussion and edit/change.
- If on-topic, users will vote to keep it. After reaching certain vote count, tag will be allowed to be used anywhere.
- Alternatively, users will take other necessary action (like merge, synonym, rename, discuss on meta etc.) applicable.
- Hopefully, users will also create tag wiki for the tag while this time.
- Let this process run for certain days. If enough (up or down) votes are not accumulated within this time, let the tag remain and use as usual. At least, community had a chance to kill the bad tag at its birth.

This way, the tag created will already have been passed through the eyes of community. Most probably, it will be a good tag.

This may not be 100% solution for all problems related to tags; but I hope this will bring down too much work needed now for maintaining the tags.

I am not expert in handling the tags. I prefer to tag this as [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) than [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). Any change/suggestion/improvement in this proposal is fine provided that somehow, there should be a watch of community while creating the tags.

As commented by @Erik_A, similar but very basic feature exists for 10000+ users. It looks that this proposal cover more users (5000+) and makes it easy to handle new tags.

Comment: Note that users with >10K rep get the _Access to moderator tool_ privilege, where they can see newly created tags and nip them in the bud if they're bad. For the last few months, I've been trying to check that weekly and prevent bad tags from getting created.

Comment: @ErikA: I was not aware about this feature exists. This looks somewhat similar in objective that I am proposing here.

Comment: Well, it's a lot more basic than what you're proposing. It's just a list of newly created tags + question count per tag, that's all. If you want to remove a tag, you have to remove it from all questions, and if no-one checks (or cares), it quietly disappears from that overview

Comment: You don't even need 10k rep to monitor them. The [Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) has a "new" filter to list newly created tags. //cc @ErikA

Comment: @AndrewT.: Ok; that way, I at least _know_ what new tag is being created. I can use my privileges to synonym if applicable. What next? Who will look at that request as there is no common platform or procedure to follow? Only option I can see is to post on meta. Other limitation is that, I alone doing this may not be enough as I am not expert in all the technologies and tags. If there is a procedure laid down, experts will automatically be interested and will participate.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the burnination system is rather backlogged right now, only a small percent of the tags are ever considered for burnination. There are over 78,000 tags (which is admittedly quite a few), but right now [only 421 of them are even being proposed for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+-status-completed+-status-declined) (which is only 0.5%). Admittedly, most of these tags probably aren't used very often, but [that's not necessarily evidence that the tags should be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377637/should-we-burninate-the-pyth-tag) (or that they shouldn't have been added in the first place).

By the time you have 1500 reputation, you should (hopefully) have a pretty good sense of how the site works.

I really don't see sufficient evidence that this is needed.

Comment: And maybe more importantly: Burnination requests are often done by users that are not in any way involved with that tag and they stil manage to get these tags removed. If we now bring tag creation to meta as well, I'm sure even more users that will never use a proposed tag are going to vote against its creation with all reasons they can dream-up but none of those reasons will ever pan out if the tag had been created.

Comment: @rene One thing I've learned from participating in the beta sites is that sometimes the best answer to a question like "should this tag be created?" is "try it and see how it works."

Comment: Apparently, I still do not have enough sense of how the site works. I should more involve on meta; hopefully, that will help.

Comment: Percentage is very small; but the work is huge. That was my point. On the site like SO, small percentage covers big count. This may not be an issue for other network sites.

Comment: @AmitJoshi The work is large only on tags that have been used (or misused) extensively. If the person who created them hadn't created them, odds are someone else would have. Would the new process you're suggesting necessarily have prevented those from being made?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: I am not expert on tag management; not sure whether it would have helped 100%. I have also mentioned this in my question that this may not be 100% solution for all situations. Just that **community had a chance** to handle it _before_ the tag usage started widely.

Comment: @AmitJoshi I'm not convinced that this would actually be less work in the long run, though (especially given how few tags are actually burninated). Plus, honestly, if I wasn't closing stuff in burninations I'd probably be closing other stuff anyway, so it's not all that big of a deal from my perspective.