# Time to [insert] this tag into the incinerator?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I'm of the opinion that [insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insert) (12,457 questions at the time of writing) is at the very least too broad, and at most not required at all. While the first thing that springs to mind with this tag is the process of `INSERT`ing a new row into a database table, the tag description seems to encompass a lot more than just this:

> Insert is an action to add information to a larger container that the information should reside within. Some examples include inserting a file into a file system, inserting a record into a database, or inserting an item into a list.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

No. It seems to cover the topic of adding any sort of data into any sort of container, be it a database row, a text box, a file, a list, other custom data structures etc. It seems like a very broad definition.

There is even already an *SQL-specific tag, [sql-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert), which covers the vast majority of these questions.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It depends. The act of inserting new data is a fundamental one, but are often implicitly covered by other tags. It's natural to assume that database software has the ability to `INSERT` data into a table, it's natural to assume that mutable list structures can have new elements inserted at a specified index, it's natural to assume that text can be inserted into a UI text field.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, as described above the ability to insert data is an implicitly defined aspect of other various technologies and should be covered by those respective tags.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. While the act of adding new data is common, the purpose and methodology varies wildly. For example the tag is currently used for:

- Questions surrounding the `INSERT` keyword in various database query languages, including triggers, restrictions and cascading rules. This is also mostly covered by the [sql-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert) tag.
- Adding new data to an in-memory data structure such as a List
- Creating new UI elements such as images, typically after the UI is first displayed to the user
- Adding new data to a filesystem file at a given position

I just feel that the tag is way too broad as it stands, and at the very least its scope should be narrowed significantly. Alternatively, retag database-related questions with [sql-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert) and burn the rest.

Comment: Entry #18 on the >10k sized tags. These would ideally be handled _after_ all the smaller sized burninations (the current calculations is at 9+ years)

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh there no rush on it, just an idea to have it in the backlog and revisit it in 6 to 8, if meta agrees with the proposal of course.

Comment: 6 to 8 is actually worse. It means an infinite amount of time ... I'm atleast giving you a timeline...

Comment: 10 years is as good as 6 to 8 in this case :)

Comment: We really should have a literal *Burn* button that deletes the tag from all questions that uses it. It'd be mods-only (obviously) and would require approval from like 5 others before it occurs (maybe even SO staff escalation). How does that sound @BhargavRao, especially considering your enormous expertise in the tag burnination zone?

Comment: @JackBashford: Great suggestion; may be you should consider feature request. I have bit different approach for this problem. I raised a [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386549/5779732) yesterday on meta; but community disagreed.

Comment: No worries @AmitJoshi - I'll make a question now. (Another feature request - we need to have different names for things. A feature request isn't a "question" - it's more like a "proposal" or an "announcement", or even a general "post").

Comment: @AmitJoshi Fifteen minutes later... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386599/10221765

Comment: @JackBashford, that system is already present, and we use it in the cases of 1k-10k sized burninations.

Comment: So really we'd just need to retag ~2500 questions to get it under 10k, then that took could be used.

Comment: It doesn't work like that @jhpratt, the number 10k is just a ballpark estimate. The categories are "I can do this alone", "I can do this with other users help", "Other users and myself can do it, but a CM needs to be involved at the end" and "Nah, I can't do it, ask the CM to delete".  This tag is still in the 4th category.

Comment: @BhargavRao No, it would ideally be handled when we make the burn process not absurdly time consuming or come up with an alternate process for tags that are too big to do manually. We're only handicapped from removing these because our burn process is insane.

Comment: Feel free to propose a new FR on meta, @jpmc26.